# R Unexpected line feed after tk_choose.dir

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

When using the folder picker `tk_choose.dir` from the `tcltk` module in R, I get intermittent and unexpected line feeds in the console afterward. Whatever I try to get rid of it, nothing works but restarting R Studio.

Example:

```
library(tcltk)

FolderName <- tk_choose.dir("C:/")
```

Does anyone know what triggers this line feed and how to avoid it? Up until now the internet hasn't been really helpful.

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
RStudio 0.99.896
tcltk 3.3.0
Windows 7
```

Comment: Can you provide a small code example which shows this?

Comment: On R 3.2.2, I can't get the function to work at all in Rstudio. Outside, it works fine.

Comment: What version of tcl/tk is it using?